# Word for individual rice grain?

Tags: single-word-requests

Rice uncooked is a collection of rice grains. Once they are cooked, I feel grain is not the right term for it. Like a corn kernel, what is the term used for a cooked rice grain (cooked in a batch)?

Sorry if it is ambiguous. I am not able to describe it well.

Comment: A grain of rice is a grain of rice. That's your term.

Comment: "Long-grain rice like Basmati and Jasmin is typically used for side dishes and salads. When cooked, **the grains** have a firm, dry texture".

Comment: Yes, a cooked grain of rice.

Comment: Generally, once rice is  cooked, we don't talk about grains.

Comment: All right then!

Comment: I talk about grains after rice is cooked. I may say that they stick together or not, depending on cooking technique and variety. This is normal in culinary writing, [e.g.](https://www.finecooking.com/article/the-science-of-cooking-rice) "We’ve cooked rice countless times and countless ways ... Sometimes each grain is tender yet chewy, separate, and fluffy. Other times, the grains just clump together." _The Science of Cooking Rice_ David Joachim and Andrew Schloss.

Comment: It is possible that a better answer to this question will be obtained on the Seasoned Advice Stack Exchange than here.

Comment: Some kinds of rice turn into a glutinous mass when cooked, and you can't easily see the grains any more; I have seen this with Malay and Singapore cuisine. There are other rice types which don't do this. Sometimes it's nice to make non-sticky rice oily so that each cooked grain is coated with oil or butter. I would be interested to know how one might discuss this if they aren't "grains" any more.